# Вывести список ответов на комментарии пользователя

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в wordpress вывести список ответов на комментарии пользователя с определенным id.

То есть, мы имеем id пользователя, надо вывести на страницу список ответов, которые оставили другие пользователи на его комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$user_id = 15; /* id пользователя, ответы на комментарии которого нужно получить */
$comments_ids = array(); /* сюда будем помещать id комментариев пользователя */

/* получим комментарии пользователя */
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'user_id' => $user_id
));
/* для каждого комментария узнаем его id и поместим в массив $comments_ids */
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $comment_id = $comment->comment_ID;
    array_push($comments_ids, $comment_id);
}
/* теперь выберем все дочерние комментарии, родителем которых
   является один из комментариев массива $comments_ids,
   исключив из них комментарии пользователя */
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'parent__in' => $comments_ids,
    'author__not_in' => $user_id
));
/* выведем автора и текст каждого из полученных комментариев */
foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo('Автор: ' . $comment->comment_author);
    echo('Текст комментария: ' . $comment->comment_content);
}
```